# Regex with looping character or condition

Tags: php, regex

Below sample correct data

```
Hello @[Reda Sel](Native:reda) Hello @[Peter K](Native:123456)
```

I using this regex

```
(\@\[.*?])(\(.*?:.*?\))
```

to get the data like

```
@[Reda Sel](Native:reda)
@[Peter K](Native:123456)
```

the problem is, when the input data something like this

```
Hello @[Reda Sel] Hello. @[Peter K](Native:123456) Testing
Hello @[Reda Sel](Native:reda) Hello @[Peter K](Native:123456)
```

The result is

```
@[Reda Sel] Hello. @[Peter K](Native:123456)
@[Reda Sel](Native:reda)
@[Peter K](Native:123456)
```

I need to capture the data with certain expression like the example above.
But if the data is repeated, the result is not overlapping like that.
And the result would be like this

```
@[Peter K](Native:123456)
@[Reda Sel](Native:reda)
@[Peter K](Native:123456)
```

Edited if I wanted to replace the data using the result value like

```
Hello Reda Sel
```

Should I use foreach and replace it one, by one, or is there any other regex options?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is the initial `.*?`, I would use negated character classes here instead ...

```
(@\[[^]]*])(\([^:]*:[^)]*\))
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aM6rJ9/2)

Comment: Should I using foreach if I wanted to replace the data with the result value like Hello Reda Sel, or is there any other method to get the data inside the @[..] selector?

Comment: If you want the data inside, rearrange the capture groups. See here https://regex101.com/r/aM6rJ9/3